Extra closing tag added when pasting HTML code in Visual Studio Code
I'm encountering an issue in Visual Studio Code when pasting HTML code, where an extra closing tag is automatically inserted, messing up the structure of my code. This happens with even the simplest HTML snippets.
Example:
When I copy and paste this simple HTML:
<footer>
    <p>Hi</p>
</footer>

It pastes as:
<footer></footer>
    <p>Hi</p>
</footer>

An unexpected closing  tag is added at the top, which is incorrect and breaks my code.
What I've tried

Disabled auto-formatting settings:

"editor.formatOnPaste": false
"editor.formatOnSave": false
"editor.defaultFormatter": null


Disabled Emmet:

"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": false


Disabled extensions:
Auto Close Tag, Auto Rename Tag, Prettier.

Tried setting Prettier as the default formatter, but no change.

Checked the Problems Panel, but there are no errors reported.

I've also reset all settings to default and even reinstalled VS Code, but the issue still occurs.


Environment:
Visual Studio Code version: 1.93
OS: Windows
HTML-related extensions installed: Prettier, Auto Close Tag, Auto Rename Tag, Live Server.
I can't find a solution to prevent this auto-insertion of an extra closing tag. Any help would be appreciated!

Did you restart the VS Code after disabling extensions?

This setting will fix the issue if you turn it off:
Settings > HTML: Auto Closing Tags. It does however mean it wont work like it used to when it worked well

I have that too, I'd say it's a bug. I tried disabling all extensions and restarting. Still the same problem.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/227859

I have had the same issue, very annoying. What helped it for me (and still keeping the functionality when writing new tags) was installing the extension "Paste and Indent". However, it still works a little bit strangely, but that may be because of me having vim as an extension, so that I cannot paste when in insert mode (then it still gets the extra closing tag), and I must use the right click menu to paste, keyboard shortcut not working.

I ran into this after adding the Prettier extension for the first time yesterday. I was able to fix it by changing the default html formatter in settings.json:
"[html]": {
 "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
}


This was a bug - if you upgrade to v1.94 or later, it should be fixed.
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/227859
